# when cloudera manage agent installing, No module named cmf.alternatives error occured

Tags: python, cloudera

I am installing cloudera cluster for first time.

On the Cluster Installing page, Show some messages like:

```
Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat from agent.

     Ensure that the host's hostname is configured properly.

     Ensure that port 7182 is accessible on the Cloudera Manager server (check firewall rules).

     Ensure that ports 9000 and 9001 are free on the host being added.

     Check agent logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/ on the host being added (some of the logs can be found in the installation details).
```

**Then in the log file, I found:**

```
[21/Oct/2014 05:29:54 +0000] 9155 MainThread agent ERROR Failed to connect to previous supervisor.
.....

SystemExit: 2
```

**In the /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/cloudera-scm-agent.out file, I found:**

```
[21/Oct/2014 11:29:15 +0000] 1658 MainThread agent        INFO     Logging to /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/cloudera-scm-agent.log
Error: could not find config file /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/supervisor/supervisord.conf
For help, use /usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/agent.py -h

....

Session terminated, killing shell... ...killed.
```

**And I run :** /usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/agent.py -h

***The System tell me :***

```
/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/agent.py:24: DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead

import sha

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/agent.py", line 40, in <module>

    import cmf.alternatives

ImportError: No module named cmf.alternatives
```

**My ENV is:** centos 6.5, Python 2.6.6, Cloudera manage server is 5.2

So, I want to know which module/modules would be installed to fix this error.

Or How to config to use the cmf module in the installion?

And where I can find a doc which describe the python for the cloudera?
   Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can simply follow the instructions, replace `sha` with `hashlib` and try again.

```
...
# import sha
import hashlib

# and use hashlib.sha1 instead of sha.sha in the following code
hashlib.sha1(...)
...
```

Comment: I think sha just deprecated. But cannot find cmf.alternatives, This is the more important.

Comment: @paladinchen I think cmf.alternatives is not a 3PP module. Where did you get this file '/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/agent.py'? You may have to look into installation of cloudera cluster to find answers.

Comment: I found this info from  /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/cloudera-scm-agent.out